# \DeclareUnicodeCharacter doesn't work for all characters

Tags: unicode

I am trying to incorporate some Unicode characters into my LaTeX files. All characters I added so far worked well, but when I use

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{211D}{{\mathbb R}}
```

(211D is the Unicode character ℝ, i.e. what would be denoted `\mathbb{R}` in LaTeX), I get an error message

```
Undefined control sequence ℝ
```

The problem is dependent neither on what is "…" in `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{211D}{…}`, nor on whether the character ℝ is used in math mode or not. For most other Unicode characters (even those with higher numbers), `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` works as expected, but I get the same error also for other double stroke letters (e.g. ℂ). Do you have any idea why this is so and how to make it work?

Comment: Have you got `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` in your preamble?

Comment: Of course, that's where the macro \DeclareUnicodeCharacter is defined.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{211D}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}
$ℝ$
\end{document}
```

You probably forgot to load **amssymb**. By the way, there's a different way to define such symbols without looking in Unicode tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ℝ}{\mathbb{R}}

\begin{document}
$ℝ$
\end{document}
```

Notice also that the correct syntax is `\mathbb{R}` rather than `{\mathbb R}`.

Comment: Strange, it was indeed missing amssymb, but I was almost sure that I tested it also with simple 'test' instead of \mathbb{R} to make sure that \mathbb is not the problem. I was solving several issues at once and have probably mistaken it with some other character (I shouldn't ask such questions at 2 AM). Thank you for the solution.

Comment: As for the rest – I know about the newunicodechar, but I would like to make it possible to build my files everywhere and this package is not standardly included (at least not in my distribution).

Comment: And lastly – \mathbb R and \mathbb{R} is the same, I just wanted to make sure that there wouldn't be any problem with using this character as a parameter of a macro when not using {} (I like to write things like \frac12, \sqrt2 etc. and I have had some issues when the parameter was a macro whose content was not surrounded by {}, but this was all in XeLaTeX and it doesn't seem to be an issue here).

Comment: Of course `\mathbb R` and `\mathbb{R}` are the same. But definitely `\mathbb{RX}` and `{\mathbb RX}` aren't. Usually `\mathbb` isn't used like this, but `\mathcal` sometimes is.

Comment: I'd never heard of `newunicodecharacter` - very useful. Also, I apologise for forgetting to acknowledge this answer when answering a question. (It was by email so I cannot, unfortunately, edit it retrospectively.)

Comment: Usually when you use your unicode, you don't want to worry about the math-mode, so instead declare: `\newunicodechar{ℝ}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}}`. Now ℝ can be used without the dollar, `$`, symbols! :-)

Comment: @MusaAl-hassy `\ensuremath` is considered bad practise by some.

Comment: @MusaAl-hassy I don't think it's good practice: ℝ`ℝ` is a math symbol anyway, so it should be properly segregated.

Comment: @Skillmon why do you say that? I've seen it often and so have used it for that reason; it also makes things work for me. egreg what do you mean?

Comment: @MusaAl-hassy it leads to bad markup. Math stuff should be recognizable as such.