# How to render unicode symbols?

Tags: symbols, unicode, verbatim

I have the following latex code.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
█ [1:0x561b3f574358] <list>
├─[2:0x561b3e9cd938] <dbl>
├─[3:0x561b3e9cd900] <dbl>
└─[4:0x561b3e9cd8c8] <dbl>
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

The rendering result is as follows. The symbols on the left are not displayed.

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679166/unicode-character-not-set-up-for-use-with-latex-error/679171#679171

Comment: You probably additionally want `\tracinglostchars=3`, so a missing character is considered an error, instead of failing silently and hoping you notice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend to use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and a font, that provides the used symbols, e.g.

```
% Use this with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX not PDFLaTeX.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertinus}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
█ [1:0x561b3f574358] <list>
├─[2:0x561b3e9cd938] <dbl>
├─[3:0x561b3e9cd900] <dbl>
└─[4:0x561b3e9cd8c8] <dbl>
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image: using LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX]

If you want to use PDFLaTeX, you can declare the missing unicode characters, e.g., using `\rule` commands:

```
% Use this with PDFLaTeX, not XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX!
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2588}{\rule{1ex}{\ht\strutbox}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{251C}{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{.4pt}{\baselineskip}%
  \rule[.2\baselineskip]{1ex}{.4pt}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2500}{\rule[.2\baselineskip]{1ex}{.4pt}}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2514}{\rule[.2\baselineskip]{.4pt}{.5\baselineskip}%
  \rule[.2\baselineskip]{1ex}{.4pt}}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
█ [1:0x561b3f574358] <list>
├─[2:0x561b3e9cd938] <dbl>
├─[3:0x561b3e9cd900] <dbl>
└─[4:0x561b3e9cd8c8] <dbl>
\end{verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image: using PDFLaTeX]

Answer (score 7):

You can use `pmboxdraw`, but blocks are too wide, so I replace `\textblock` (corresponding to U+2588) with `\textlfblock` (corresponding to U+258C) with the width limited to 0.5em.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2588}{\makebox[0.5em][l]{\textlfblock}}

\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
█ [1:0x561b3f574358] <list>
├─[2:0x561b3e9cd938] <dbl>
├─[3:0x561b3e9cd900] <dbl>
└─[4:0x561b3e9cd8c8] <dbl>
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Beside the main issue (render some symbols) that is already solved, may be you want to explore other alternatives to render directory trees that verbatim. Here just a  comparison with a similar result using the old `dirtree` and the much more versatil `forest`:

[image: mwe]

```
% Use this with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX not PDFLaTeX.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertinus}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{dirtree}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{3}
\section{verbatim}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{verbatim}
█ [1:0x561b3f574358] <list>
├─[2:0x561b3e9cd938] <dbl>
├─[3:0x561b3e9cd900] <dbl>
└─[4:0x561b3e9cd8c8] <dbl>
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
\newcolumn

\section{dirtree}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\setlength{\DTbaselineskip}{12pt}        % optional
\DTsetlength{1pt}{6pt}{5pt}{.4pt}{.4pt} % optional
\ttfamily
\dirtree{%
.1 \rule[-.35em]{11.6pt}{1.5em} 
[1:0x561b3f574358] <list>. 
.2 [2:0x561b3e9cd938] <dbl>. 
.2 [3:0x561b3e9cd900] <dbl>. 
.2 [4:0x561b3e9cd8c8] <dbl>. 
}
\end{minipage}
\newcolumn

\section{forest}
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\begin{forest}
forked edges, for tree={ grow'=0, folder, font=\ttfamily, s sep=1pt
}
[\mbox{[1:0x561b3f574358] <list>}, fill=gray!10, draw
[\mbox{[2:0x561b3e9cd938] <dbl>}]
[\mbox{[3:0x561b3e9cd900] <dbl>}]
[\mbox{[4:0x561b3e9cd8c8] <dbl>}]
]
\end{forest}
\end{minipage}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```