Unicode character └ (U+2514) not set up with LaTeX (when using) pandoc with markdown text file
I am trying to compile in a pdf the following markdown file (ex.md):
Some text

```text
folder1/
└── folder2/
    ├── folder3/
    │   ├── file1
    │   └── file2
    └── folder4/
        ├── file3
        └── file4
```

With the following command:
pandoc ex.md -o ex.pdf

but I get the following error
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: Unicode character └ (U+2514)
               not set up for use with LaTeX.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?
Edit
I tried to edit the text file as follows:
---
title: My title
author: My name
header-includes:
  - '`\usepackage{pmboxdraw}'
---

Some text

```{verbatim}
.
├── 01_check_internet.sh
├── 02_install_packages.sh
├── 03_add_to_install.zsh
├── ex.md
├── so.txt
├── StarterKit.md
└── StarterKit.pdf

0 directories, 7 files
```

But got the following error:
Error producing PDF.
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.48 `

Edit2
I also tried the following:
$ pandoc ex.md -o -s ex.tex


with the following tex file:
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
%
\documentclass[
]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\ifnum 0\ifxetex 1\fi\ifluatex 1\fi=0 % if pdftex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage{textcomp} % provide euro and other symbols
\else % if luatex or xetex
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}
\fi
% Use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{% use microtype if available
  \usepackage[]{microtype}
  \UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
}{}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{KOMAClassName}{% if non-KOMA class
  \IfFileExists{parskip.sty}{%
    \usepackage{parskip}
  }{% else
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}}
}{% if KOMA class
  \KOMAoptions{parskip=half}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{xcolor}
\IfFileExists{xurl.sty}{\usepackage{xurl}}{} % add URL line breaks if available
\IfFileExists{bookmark.sty}{\usepackage{bookmark}}{\usepackage{hyperref}}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={My title},
  pdfauthor={My name},
  hidelinks,
  pdfcreator={LaTeX via pandoc}}
\urlstyle{same} % disable monospaced font for URLs
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em} % prevent overfull lines
\providecommand{\tightlist}{%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-\maxdimen} % remove section numbering
\usepackage{pmboxdraw}

\title{My title}
\author{My name}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Some text

\begin{verbatim}
.
├── 01_check_internet.sh
├── 02_install_packages.sh
├── 03_add_to_install.zsh
├── ex.md
├── so.txt
├── StarterKit.md
└── StarterKit.pdf

0 directories, 7 files
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}



Can you show the intermedia .tex file?

Do you perhaps mean -o instead of -od?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you I corrected the typo

Add  \usepackage{pmboxdraw}  to your header-includes

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I did not see any intermediate .tex file after failed compiling of the file, should?

pandoc automatically throws away all the helpful files. You can regenerate at least the .tex file with pandoc ex.md -s -o ex.tex

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I tried the package in include header-includes but there is still a problem. I posted the code in the edited question

Don't use code fences if you want to show code fences in your question. Your closing code fences are always invisible. Instead indent the code by 4 spaces.

Use - \usepackage{pmboxdraw} , no funny quotation marks around it

pandoc ex.md -o -s ex.tex: Please note the order of -s and -o in my comment above. ex.tex is the value for the -o option, not for the -s option

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz sorry for the imprecision. I re-ran the code with the tex file in the edited question

Your new .tex file works fine for me. If you now switch back to creating the pdf file pandoc ex.md -o ex.pdf, does it work?

In the meantime it worked also for me! many thanks! I think the reason was 1. no header-includes and 2. the funny quotations marks around. Many thanks. If you want to post an answer I will be glad to accept it!

Posting answers isn't possible if the question is marked as duplicate. I voted to reopen in order to post an answer tailored for this specific situation. Let's see if this gets reopend.

Ok, let's see if it gets reopened as you provided the the practical working solution which the proposed answer did not. Let's that the big guys with all the priviledge up there also see it

The "size" of the user does not directly correlate to closing privileges. These are based on the experience in the respective tag. (although David is a bit taller than me and he can close unicode questions and Joseph is a lot taller than me and he can close all kinds of questions, so maybe your theory isn't completely wrong :) )

You all guy know each others :). Anyway a big thank you: just learned a lot

Keep an eye open for TeX User Group meetings near you and you could meet many interesting people :) (The next one will be in Prague https://tug.org/tug2024/ )

Ok thanks, I'll check it out :)

sorry gold badge closed:-) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/679166/unicode-character-not-set-up-for-use-with-latex-error/679171#679171 shows the tex issue but not how to fix that from pandoc

In general Unicode character not set up for use with LaTeX error shows you how to add missing unicode characters.
However in your specific case, you are lucky and just adding \usepackage{pmboxdraw} will add all the characters necessary for your example. You can add the package to your markdown file via header includes like this:
---
title: My title
author: My name
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{pmboxdraw}
---

Some text

```verbatim
.
├── 01_check_internet.sh
├── 02_install_packages.sh
├── 03_add_to_install.zsh
├── ex.md
├── so.txt
├── StarterKit.md
└── StarterKit.pdf

0 directories, 7 files
```



+1 very nice, didn't know that package

@DG' Thanks! The package is very useful for such kinds of diagrams.
