# New Twitter symbol ?

Tags: symbols, unicode

I am trying to write the new Twitter symbol to a file

[image]

but I don't understand how to use `declareunicodecharacter` in this case. Does anyone know if it can be generated  ?

Comment: With `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter`, are you perhaps looking for something like this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29462

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work (I think I really don't know how to do it correctly, that's why I'm looking for guidance)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although you asked for a lowercase x, the new logo for Twitter is actually an uppercase blackboard X.

Here's a solution for **pdfLaTeX**. You can replace `\mathbb` and `\mathbbm` with `\mathbbmss` to get sans serif if you're trying to mimic the new Twitter logo.

```tex
%!TeX program = pdfLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Use these two lines for uppercase X:
\usepackage{amssymb}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1D54F}{$\mathbb{X}$}

% Use these two lines for lowercase X:
\usepackage{bbm}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{1D569}{$\mathbbm{x}$}

\begin{document}

Uppercase:  \qquad Lowercase: 

\end{document}
```

[image: Image shows blackboard bold letters uppercase X and lowercase x in a serif font.]

---

With **XeLaTeX** or **LuaLaTeX**, and **Latin Modern Math**, you can skip `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` and use Unicode directly in your input.

```tex
%!TeX program = XeLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}

Uppercase:  \qquad Lowercase: 

\end{document}
```

[image: Image shows blackboard bold letters uppercase X and lowercase x in a sans font.]

Comment: this answer is excellent. 

it could be further improved by setting the default response in code to print sans serif